# capture address value in a span class and pass it to google map url as querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, dictionary

I am in trouble because this is inside an xsl template so each time it spits out a row, the span class stores the row value so if there are three items, the span class will be holding three address values which gets passed to the google map url instead of one at a time...The jquery i am using is :

```
$('.HospitalAddressHidden').each(function(index) {
    var LocationAddress=$(".HospitalAddressHidden").text(); 
    $(".MapDirections > a").prop("href", function (index, oldHref) {
    return oldHref + LocationAddress;
    }); 
});
```

Now this does work except it passes all the addresses for all the items xsl has returned like this:-
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=86th Street West,Indianapolis IN 4626024 Joliet street ,Dyer IN 463112001 86th Street West,Indianapolis IN 4626024 Joliet street ,Dyer IN 46311

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
    <span class="HospitalAddressHidden">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ADDRESS_LINE_1,',',@CITY,' ',@STATE,' ',@ZIP)" />
    </span>

    <span class="MapDirections" style="padding-top:10px">
        <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=">Maps &#38; Directions</a>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(this)` instead of the selector again since that will select all spans with that class. Using `$(this).text()` will give you the text of the current item in the iteration. Also, I would recommend you to use jQuery's traversal behaviour to get the next `.MapDirections > a` instead of selecting all `.MapDirections > a`

```
$('.HospitalAddressHidden').each(function(index) {
    var LocationAddress=$(this).text(); 
    $(this).next('.MapDirections').find('a').prop("href", function (index, oldHref) {
        return oldHref + LocationAddress;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Note, I just assumed that you'd want to update only the next `.MapDirections > a` and not all.

Comment: one at a time..so each address will have a maps and directions link underneath them and when the link is clicked the corresponindg address should be grabbed and passed to the map url as a querystring..