# grab span text using jquery and pass as query

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, query-string, inline

```
<span class="MapDirections" style="padding-top:10px">
                                        <span class="HosAddHidden" style="display:none;">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ADDRESS_LINE_1,',',@CITY,' ',@STATE,' ',@ZIP)" />
                                            </span>
                                        <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=">Maps &#38; Directions</a>
</span>
```

How do I grab the span class HosAddHidden text which is some address and pass it to the the map url like this:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" onclick="location.href=...." return false;>Maps and directions</a>
```

Comment: $('.HospitalAddressHidden').each(function(index) {     
   var LocationAddress=$(this).text(); 
   $(".MapDirections > a").prop("href", function (index, oldHref) {
      return oldHref + LocationAddress;
   });       
  });

Comment: possible duplicate of [capture address value in a span class and pass it to google map url as querystring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195419/capture-address-value-in-a-span-class-and-pass-it-to-google-map-url-as-querystri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your response above that you have multiple `HosAddHidden`. Provided each one is followed by the anchor you want to manipulate (as your example above), you want to loop over each of the hidden addresses and change the `href` of the anchor following it. Here you go:

```
$('.HosAddHidden').each(function(index) {
    $(this).next().attr('href', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q='+$(this).text());
});
```

Note, this is not on an onclick, but rather should be run when the dom loads and changes all the anchors for you. The benefit of not putting it on an onclick is the actual href has already been changed, so someone can right-click the anchor and copy-it, open in new tab, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead on using inline click handler. You can use `text()` to grab the text from span which you can select using `.HosAddHidden` class selector.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = $(this).href + $.trim($('.HosAddHidden').text());
});
```